# Display children of the category a post is assigned to

Tags: categories

The following code works to display all child categories of a parent (when viewing a parent category), and all siblings of a child category (when viewing a child category) within sidebar.php. The same sidebar is pulled into both posts and pages.

I'd like to take it a step further so it also works when viewing a post, instead of only categories and child categories. On a post, I'd like all child categories of the category assigned to a post to display. After spending countless hours, I'm at a loss. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    <ul>                
            <?php if (is_category( )) {                             
                  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
                  $thiscat = get_category ($cat);
                  $parent = $thiscat->parent;
                  $img = get_option('z_taxonomy_image' . $thiscat->term_id);

                  if ($parent != '') {

                        wp_list_categories( array(
                        'child_of' => $parent,
                        'exclude' => $cat,
                        'title_li' => 0
                    ) );
                    }

                  else {

                        wp_list_categories( array(
                        'child_of' => $cat,
                        'title_li' => 0
                    ) );
                  }

            } 
            ?>

            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

get the category or categories of the single post with `get_the_category()` and loop through them, calling the child category lists if available.

```
<ul>
<?php 
if( is_single() ) {
    $post_cats = get_the_category();
        foreach( $post_cats as $post_cat ) {
            wp_list_categories( array(
                'child_of' => $post_cat->term_id,
                'title_li' => 0,
                'show_option_none' => ''
            ) );
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: See [this link](http://www.thevaccinereaction.org/2016/12/texas-plans-to-restrict-vaccine-exemptions/) for an example sidebar like mine. The below lists the subcategory assigned my post instead of all subs under same parent:  

    `<?php  if( is_single() ) {
        $cats = array();
     foreach (get_the_category($post_id) as $c) {
     $cat = get_category($c);
     array_push($cats, $cat->name);
     }

     if (sizeOf($cats) > 0) {
     $post_categories = implode(', ', $cats);
     } else {
     $post_categories = 'Not Assigned';
     }

     echo $post_categories;
} ?>`

Comment: I apologize the formatting wouldn't take in my comment above. Do you have any suggestions on how I could list not just the sub-category assigned to my post, but all other siblings as well? The code you sent didn't display any categories assigned to my post.

Comment: This helped with something else. Thanks Michael.